# C++ Builder __property definition with macros

Tags: c++, properties, macros

I am using C++ Builder 10.2.3

I am trying to add properties to different classes (about 10).

For example in one class I added:

```cpp
__property UnicodeString sdkPath = {read=get_sdkPath, write=set_sdkPath};
ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, sdkPath, "")
    
__property UnicodeString algorithm = {read=get_algorithm, write=set_algorithm};
ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, algorithm, "")
```

`ER_PROPERTY` is defined as:

```cpp
#define ER_PROPERTY(TYPE,NAME,DEFAULT);                  
TYPE get_##NAME() const { return NAME; }                
void set_##NAME(TYPE the_##NAME) { NAME = the_##NAME; }
```

The problem is that during execution, I am getting a StackOverflow error message.

Is there a problem to use the `__property` definition with macros like that?
Because macros are not supposed to take space in memory. They are just replaced?

The purpose is to generate RTTI properties I can manipulate at run-time.
Below is an example of code to get the RTTI at run-time:

```
TRttiContext RttiCtx;
    TRttiInstanceType *QInstanceType =
        dynamic_cast<TRttiInstanceType*>(RttiCtx.GetType(this->ClassType()));
OR
    TRttiInstanceType *QInstanceType =
        dynamic_cast<TRttiInstanceType*>(RttiCtx.GetType((PTypeInfo)this->ClassInfo());
```

The problem is that I cannot use FindType and GetTypes methods to get Delphi RTTI for classes I have defined in C++ language.
So, is there another way I can get access to the RTTI for the properties I added to my C++ classes? All the classes I defined are primarily derived from TObject.

For sure I cannot add the complete code because it will be too long. But I am adding some pieces. Hope that it will help to reproduce:

```
        class QObject : public TPersistent
        {
            int firstAvailablePropertyIdx;
    
       public:
        void setProperty(const UnicodeString &name, Variant value);
        
        private:
            friend class Context;
        }
        
        class Context : public QObject
        {
        public:
        
                ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, sdkPath, "");
                ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, algorithm, "");
                ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, log, "");
        
                ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, path, "");
        
                ER_PROPERTY(int, parallelism, std::max(1, TThread::ProcessorCount + 1));
    
            void setProperty(const UnicodeString &key, const UnicodeString &value);
        }
        
        void QObject::setProperty(const UnicodeString &name, Variant value)
        {    
            TRttiContext RttiCtx;
            TRttiInstanceType *QInstanceType =
                dynamic_cast<TRttiInstanceType*>(RttiCtx.GetType(this->ClassType()));
            DynamicArray<TRttiProperty*> GlobProperty = QInstanceType->GetProperties();
        
        }

void Context::setProperty(const UnicodeString &key, const UnicodeString &value)
{
    QObject::setProperty(key, value.IsEmpty() ? Variant(true) : Variant(value));
}
        
        Context *Globals = new Context();
        Globals->setProperty("sdkPath","Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, a multi-line macro needs to have a `\` at the end of each line that continues the macro to the next line, eg:

```cpp
#define ER_PROPERTY(TYPE,NAME,DEFAULT); \
TYPE get_##NAME() const { return NAME; } \
void set_##NAME(TYPE the_##NAME) { NAME = the_##NAME; }
```

Second, if you actually expand out each use of `ER_PROPERTY()`, the problem should become quite obvious to you:

```cpp
__property UnicodeString sdkPath = {read=get_sdkPath, write=set_sdkPath};
//ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, sdkPath, "")
;UnicodeString get_sdkPath() const { return sdkPath; }
void set_sdkPath(UnicodeString the_sdkPath) { sdkPath = the_sdkPath; }
    
__property UnicodeString algorithm = {read=get_algorithm, write=set_algorithm};
//ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, algorithm, "")
;UnicodeString get_algorithm() const { return algorithm; }
void set_algorithm(UnicodeString the_algorithm) { algorithm = the_algorithm; }
```

For one thing, the initial `;` is erroneous needs to be removed.

But more importantly, each getter method is reading from its respective property, which calls the getter method, which reads from the property, which calls the getter, ... and so on in an endless recursive loop.

Likewise with the setter methods.  Each setter method is writing to its respective property, which calls the setter method, which writes to the property, which calls the setter, ... and so on in an endless recursive loop.

That is why you are getting Stack Overflow errors.

You need the getter/setter methods to read/write actual data members, not the properties.

I would suggest a different approach:

```cpp
#define ER_PROPERTY(TYPE,NAME,DEFAULT) \
private: TYPE m_##NAME; \
__published: __property TYPE NAME = { read=m_##NAME, write=m_##NAME, default=DEFAULT }
```

```cpp
class SomeClass
{
    ...
    ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, sdkPath, "");
    ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, algorithm, "");
    ...
};
```

Which will expand out to this:

```cpp
class SomeClass
{
    ...
    //ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, sdkPath, "");
    private: UnicodeString m_sdkPath;
    __published: __property UnicodeString sdkPath = { read=m_sdkPath, write=m_sdkPath, default="" };

    //ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, algorithm, "");
    private: UnicodeString m_algorithm;
    __published: __property UnicodeString algorithm = { read=m_algorithm, write=m_algorithm, default="" };
    ...
};
```

Or, you can simply get rid of the `__property` declarations altogether, if you don't really need access to their generated RTTI, eg:

```cpp
#define ER_PROPERTY(TYPE,NAME,DEFAULT) \
TYPE ##NAME /* = DEFAULT */
```

```cpp
class SomeClass
{
    ...
public:
    ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, sdkPath, "");
    ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, algorithm, "");
    ...
};
```

Which will expand out to this:

```cpp
class SomeClass
{
    ...
public:
    //ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, sdkPath, "");
    UnicodeString sdkPath /* = "" */;

    //ER_PROPERTY(UnicodeString, algorithm, "");
    UnicodeString algorithm /* = "" */ ;
    ...
};
```

Note that initializing a class member inside of its declaration requires C++11 or higher, which is supported only by C++Builder's [Clang-based compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am checking in details now. But for the \ at the end of the macros, I just removed it when I was posting the question here. My mistake!

Comment: I will need few days to test to give a final response.
Because those properties are part of a bigger program of thousand of lines.
get_sdkPath, and set_sdkPath, for example, were functions I was trying to call in other functions.
Now the property is just set through a private variable m_##NAME.
I will test and post a response as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes I need to access RTTI properties. This is why I used __property
I know for Clang Compiler. My application uses OpenCV modules. So I can only use Clang compiler

Comment: I am still testing.
But I first needed to remove the default property otherwise I was getting the error message:
"expression is not an integral constant expression"
I also needed to remove the __published status otherwise I was getting the error message:
"Fields defined in a '__published' block must be of type pointer to Delphi-style class"

Comment: `UnicodeString` works just fine as a data type in `__published` properties

Comment: The properties I posted here with UnicodeString are just examples.
I have really more properties to define with other classes which are not from Delphi

Comment: `__published` properties only work with Delphi-compatible types, because of the RTTI generation.  So class types used in such properties must derive from `TObject` and be accessed by pointer. But non-published properties can use any type you want.

Comment: So far the properties seem to be added. But I cannot access the RTTI at run-time.
I just added the code I am using in my initial question.

Comment: @Louis you do now that `TRttiContext` has access to non-published members, too, don't you? In this situation, I would just get rid of the `__property`s altogether and declare public data members, and then use `TRttiType::Get[Declared]Fields()` or `TRttiType::GetField()` to access them. As for your RTTI issue, make sure your C++ classes are derived from `TObject` and are decorated with [`__declspec(delphiclass)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declspec(delphiclass)), and/or maybe [`__declspec(delphirtti)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declspec(delphirtti)).

Comment: I know for TRttiContext.
I cannot use __declspec(delphirtti) because it only works on published Delphi types.
I tried __declspec(delphiclass) but the RTTI are still not accessible.
So I am going to try TRttiType::GetField() to see if it will work.

Comment: @Louis You need to derive your class from `TObject` and mark it `__declspec(delphiclass)`, or else derive it from `TPersistent` (which already has RTTI enabled on it).

Comment: The classes were already derived from TObject. And I added also __declspec(delphiclass). I just checked for GetField() and unfortunately it requires an TRttiInstanceType which requires GetType(). So, it is the same problem, Can it work better?

Comment: I tried TPersistent insteaf of TObject. And unfortunately the result is the same: I cannot access the RTTI at run-time.

Comment: @Louis Then you are doing something wrong. Please update your question to provide a [mcve]. You don't need to access `TRttiInstanceType` directly. `GetField()` is a virtual method of `TRttiType`. Let the `TRttiContext` deal with `TRttiInstanceType` internally.

Comment: I just added some piece of code. For sure it is not the exact code. But I hope it will help to reproduce.

Comment: Were you able to test the sample code I posted here for the access to RTTI properties?

Comment: @Louis no, I didn't know you had posted new code, but even so, I don't have a working compiler installed ATM. But, just looking at the new code, `TRttiInstanceType *QInstanceType = dynamic_cast<TRttiInstanceType*>(RttiCtx.GetType(this->ClassType())); DynamicArray<TRttiProperty*> GlobProperty = QInstanceType->GetProperties();` should be `TRttiType *QType = RttiCtx.GetType(ClassType()); DynamicArray<TRttiProperty*> GlobProperty = QType->GetProperties();` And `Globals->setProperty("sdkPath","Test");` looks ambiguous since a *narrow* string literal can initialize both `UnicodeString` and `Variant`

Comment: It is just a test code line to call QObject::setProperty"
What I wanted to show is that QInstanceType->GetProperties() is always NULL"

Comment: I found what was missing. I needed to add the directive
#pragma explicit_rtti
So, the issue is resolved. I can access all the properties now!